# How to customize issue display in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

Is there a way to customize the style for the issue displayed from search?
The specific features I am looking for:

1. To be able to choose whatever fields to display and the order. The popup windows
   from "Visibility Setting" does not seem to work completely for this purpose.
2. To break down issues into groups with headings, such as priorities, milestone, etc
   (again, from user choice).

Here is the sample screen from fogbugz:

[image]

Anyway to do the same? That is the simple useful feature I assume must be already supported.

I have search the doc, but could not find an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you request is clear, but unfortunately, it's not possible.